# Does the hibernate session need to be closed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm adding some batching utility to my Spring Boot app and I'm using the session from my entity manager to do so. The batching seems to work fine but I'm wondering if I need to close my session and if there's a potential memory leak I'm missing.

As I understand it, closing a session disallows any further action on the session to occur. When I was closing the session before I encountered an error of `IllegalStateException: Session/Entity Manager is closed`. So in my case since I'm using the persistence context, I believe I don't want to clear the session.

```
@Repository
public class BatchDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}")
    private Integer batchSize;

    @Transactional
    public <S> List<S>  batchUpdate(Iterable<S> items) {

        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);

        Iterator<S> iterator = items.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            if (i > 0 && i % batchSize == 0) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }

            S item = iterator.next();
            session.update(item);
            i++;
        }

        session.flush();
        session.clear();

        // session.close(); throws exception
        return Lists.newArrayList(items);
    }

    @Transactional
    public <S> List<S> batchInsert(Iterable<S> items) {

        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);

        int i = 0;
        Iterator<S> iterator = items.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            if (i > 0 && i % batchSize == 0) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }

            S item = iterator.next();
            session.persist(item);
        }

        session.flush();
        session.clear();

        // session.close(); throws exception
        return Lists.newArrayList(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you fiddling with the `Session` anyway? And if the items are already managed objects, it's usually not necessary to call `update` inside a context.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I was using the session mostly because update() avoids the select statements that merge() has. You make a fair point tho. I updated my application to remove the batchUpdate (update is now happening where I'm setting the new values) and the batchInsert is only using the entity manager now. I'm still curious on the behavior of Session and if I need to close it if I find I need to use it

Comment: If you're using Hibernate 5, the `Session` _is_ the `EntityManager`, and `@Transactional` will handle it for you.

Comment: Ok thank you! That makes sense.